# Php - How to download folder with its content (subfolders, etc) without compression in browser?

Tags: php, download

Is it possible to download folder  without compression in browser, I mean not as a single file, but AS IS, with its subfolders and files.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure because of the language of the question, but it seems like you have a hosted php application and you want to download a specific folder in that.

You can use `wget -r` for the recursive download of the folder. Also at the same time you need to set parent so that url's outside the folder don't get downloaded.

If you have ssh access then use `scp` or `sftp` for the download. Same goes as above you need to use recursive parameter.

**Edit**

In light of edit made in question.

Short answer : is that it is not possible directly.

Long answer : If you really want it, write a javascript that parses all files in a folder, possibly make a PHP script to return the data in json format. And then make the JS open new window with the url of the file. So in short you are still going recursively in JS and downloading the file each time by opening them in new tab/window. The downside to this is that the directory structure is lost, because you can't control download location in javascript as far as i know.